# How make scrollable whitespace on start and end of recyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I would do put white space on top and on bottom of a recyclerView.

in html/css for example i can make a scrollable parent-container with fixed height and insert a child-container with adaptable height and set paddingTop and paddingBottom of child-container.

i tryed to repeat this system in layout.xml

```xml
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="50dp"
            android:paddingBottom="35dp"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            tools:itemCount="10" />

    </ScrollView>
```

but i see the "wrap_content" adapt height ONLY if that is minor of "match_parent", as the View is scrollable(in theory) (or that is what i undestand).
But this break my system because i need the child-container is NOT scrollable.

if i set `nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` cuts the elements out of the viewport, if i set "true" the recycleView scrolls normally but the whitespaces stay fixed

exist another way to get what I want?

[attempted result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTjwd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use this way by adding clipToPadding and set to false you can add white space in top and bottom

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list_data"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/view_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/view_padding"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingBottom="90dp"
    android:paddingTop="90dp"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! was really simple!